# Stone sheet shears program Joption using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, joptionpane

I am supposed to make a program of Stone, Sheet and Shears game. It involves human play and computer play coming from Math.random().. It is actually working but I have to rerun it again and again whenever I like to play. So I decided to make it infinite until 4 is entered.

Here' how it works:

Wanna play? Beat the PC!

1. Stone
2. Sheet
3. Shears
4. Quit

meaning to say when I enter 4 it will quit but it should run continuously as long as 1, 2 , or 3 is entered. How can I do that. Here's my current codes. I know the mistake is the placement of while player != 4

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class StoneSheetShears
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          String consoleStr;
          int player = 0;    
              int[] numChoices = {1,2,3,4};
              String[] strChoices = {"Stone", "Sheet", "Shears", "Quit"};
              String playerChoice = "";
              String compChoice = "";

              int computer = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
              String output = "";

             while(true)
             {
               do
               {
                  try
                  {
                      consoleStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Beat the computer\n1. Rock\n2. Paper" +
                                        "\n3. Scissors\n4. Quit ");
                      player = Integer.parseInt(consoleStr);

                      for(int x = 0; x <numChoices.length; x++)
                      {
                          if(player == numChoices[x])
                          {
                             playerChoice = strChoices[x];
                          }
                      }

                      for(int y = 0; y <numChoices.length; y++)
                      {
                          if(computer == numChoices[y])
                          {
                             compChoice = strChoices[y];
                          }
                      }
                 }

             }while(player!=4)


          catch (NumberFormatException err)
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is an error on entry",
                  "Error Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
              continue;
          }
          break;
      } 

      if (player == computer)
      {
          output = "Both are " + compChoice;
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "DRAW!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      }


      else if (player == 1)
      {
          if (computer == 2)
          {
              output = "Computer move is " + compChoice +
                      "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "You Lose!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }
          else if (computer == 3)
          {
              output = "Computer move is " + compChoice +
                      "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "You Win!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          } 
      }

      else if (player == 2)
      {
          if (computer == 3)
          {
              output = "Computer move is " + compChoice +
                      "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "You Lose!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }
          else if (computer == 1)
          {
              output = "Computer move is " + compChoice +
                      "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "You Win!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }
      }

      else if (player == 3)
      {
          if (computer == 1)
          {
              output = "Computer move is " + compChoice +
                      "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "You Lose!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }
          else if (computer == 2)
          {
              output = "Computer move is " + compChoice +
                      "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output, "You Win!",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }         
      }
}
}
```

This is basically a game wherein stone sheet and shears are the choices.

1. Human player will choose from 1 (stone), 2 (sheet), 3(shears), 4(to quit)
2. Computer player is based on math random. <del>I used arrays to define what are the moves of human player and computer.</del> (Arrays are part of Java syntax and not appropriate for a description like this.)
3. It's a draw if both have the same moves.
4. If human chooses paper and computer player is scissors obviously computer wins. The same applies to other choices.
5. <del>The player will enter another number either 1 2 or 3.</del> (This simply repeats step 1, so is unnecessary). The game will stop when 4 is entered which means to quit as stated in the prompt

My only problem is how can I make it continuously working not until 4 is entered.

Comment: I suggest that you back up and describe the steps in words without worrying about Java syntax. From there, you should be able to see your mistake. (Hint: you have two loops when you only need one.)

Comment: So the do while should replace the while(true) is that what you're saying?

Comment: Try describing the steps in words (i.e. English or your native language).

Comment: Kindly check the edited one. The steps in words are at the bottom part

Comment: I have formatted your description as a numbered list to emphasize the order of the steps. Note that this should be a description **in English** and should *not* make any reference to Java syntax (such as arrays). Your description is incomplete. Please continue by filling in step #5.

Comment: kindly check #5 above. Please help me and kindly don't move away from swing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21321/discussion-between-doha-kik-and-code-guru)

Comment: I had to log off and didn't see the invitation to chat until this morning. I have edited step 5 to be a little more clear. To emphasize a point I made earlier. We are not worried about Java syntax at this point, including arrays, Swing, etc. Those are details that we will get to once you have a solid understanding of a proposed solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
do
{
    // Your choices...
}while (player != 4);
```

Will only exit if the user selects option `4`.  You game logic should be contained within this loop (meaning you can lose the `while(true)` loop).

This is also a horrible way to present this type of application to a user.  Swing is a event driven environment, meaning you present you UI to the user and react to there interactions to it.  From the looks of you code, you've taken a basic command line program and tried to convert.  This is never a good idea.

Graphical user interfaces should rarely contain loops that control flow like this.

A better choice (IMHO), would be to create your own frame/dialog and present the options to the user.  Each option would trigger a sequence of events by which the game would either be played or terminated.

This prevents the user being bombarded with multiple popup windows, which is just annoying.

[image]

(This is just one possible interface design)

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RockPaperScissors();
    }

    public RockPaperScissors() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new GamePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        public static final int STONE = 0;
        public static final int SHEET = 1;
        public static final int SHEARS = 2;

        private JButton stoneButton;
        private JButton sheetButton;
        private JButton shearsButton;
        private JButton quitButton;

        private JLabel player;
        private JLabel computer;
        private JLabel winner;

        public GamePane() {

            winner = new JLabel("Come play", JLabel.CENTER);
            player = new JLabel("Player", JLabel.CENTER);
            computer = new JLabel("computer", JLabel.CENTER);

            stoneButton = new JButton(new GameAction("Stone", STONE));
            sheetButton = new JButton(new GameAction("Sheet", SHEET));
            shearsButton = new JButton(new GameAction("Shear", SHEARS));
            quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 4;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(winner, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            add(player, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(computer, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            add(stoneButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(sheetButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(shearsButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(quitButton, gbc);

            quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        }

        protected void play(int action) {

            int ai = (int)Math.round((Math.random() * 2));
            updateChoice("Computer", computer, ai);
            updateChoice("Player", player, action);

            if (ai == action) {
                winner.setText("Draw!");
            } else if (action == STONE) {
                if (ai == SHEET) {
                    winner.setText("Computer Wins");
                } else if (ai == SHEARS) {
                    winner.setText("Player Wins");
                }
            } else if (action == SHEET) {
                if (ai == STONE) {
                    winner.setText("Player Wins");
                } else if (ai == SHEARS) {
                    winner.setText("Computer Wins");
                }
            } else if (action == SHEARS) {
                if (ai == STONE) {
                    winner.setText("Computer Wins");
                } else if (ai == SHEET) {
                    winner.setText("Player Wins");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void updateChoice(String prefix, JLabel label, int action) {

            switch (action) {
                case STONE:
                    label.setText(prefix + " chose STONE");
                    break;
                case SHEET:
                    label.setText(prefix + " chose SHEET");
                    break;
                case SHEARS:
                    label.setText(prefix + " chose SHEARS");
                    break;
            }

        }

        public class GameAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int action;

            public GameAction(String text, int action) {
                this.action = action;
                putValue(NAME, text);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                play(action);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

As stated in the first part of the answer:

You don't need two loops.  You inner loop is preventing the outter loop from running UNTIL the user selects option `4`.

You game logic belongs in the `do-while` loop.

```
public class StoneSheetShears {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String consoleStr;
        int player = 0;
        int[] numChoices = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        String[] strChoices = {"Stone", "Sheet", "Shears", "Quit"};
        String playerChoice = "";
        String compChoice = "";

        int computer = -1; //(int) (Math.random() * 3);
        String output = "";

        do {

            try {

                consoleStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Beat the computer\n1. Rock\n2. Paper"
                        + "\n3. Scissors\n4. Quit ");

                player = Integer.parseInt(consoleStr);

                for (int x = 0; x < numChoices.length; x++) {
                    if (player == numChoices[x]) {
                        playerChoice = strChoices[x];
                    }
                }

                computer = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
                compChoice = strChoices[computer];

                if (player == computer) {
                    output = "Both are " + compChoice;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "DRAW!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else if (player == 1) {
                    if (computer == 2) {
                        output = "Computer move is " + compChoice
                                + "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "You Lose!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (computer == 3) {
                        output = "Computer move is " + compChoice
                                + "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "You Win!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else if (player == 2) {
                    if (computer == 3) {
                        output = "Computer move is " + compChoice
                                + "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "You Lose!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (computer == 1) {
                        output = "Computer move is " + compChoice
                                + "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "You Win!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else if (player == 3) {
                    if (computer == 1) {
                        output = "Computer move is " + compChoice
                                + "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "You Lose!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (computer == 2) {
                        output = "Computer move is " + compChoice
                                + "\nYour move is " + playerChoice;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "You Win!",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad choice", "Bad Choice", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

        } while (player != 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But I'm required to stay with swing. May I ask where should I put the catch (NumberFormatException err) part because there's an error whenever it is inside the while loop. thanks

Comment: The example I present IS Swing

Comment: Yeah. I mean not like the one you did. It should still be JoptionPane. My only problem is I can't make it run continuously until 4 is entered to quit. Kindly help me with the while(true) loop body I have updated my codes above but still wrong

Comment: pls help me and kindly stay with stone sheet and shears

Answer (score 0):

The steps you have given are a great start towards understanding how to fix your code (or even start over from scratch, if necessary). So far in our discussion in the comments, we have concentrated on explaining the steps in English. Let's polish these steps a little by introducing some computer programming concepts. In particular, we need a loop of some kind. However, to emphasize a major point, we are still not overly concerned with Java syntax. As long as we write something that is understandable to us, it doesn't matter whether or not a compiler will understand it. With that said, here are my proposed modifications to your description:

```
Continue while human input is not 4
    Human player will choose from 1 (stone), 2 (sheet), 3(shears), 4(to quit)
    Computer player is based on math random.
    Determine the winner (or if it's a draw).
```

Note that I am using indentation to indicate which steps are repeated in the loop. Also, I haven't gone into the details of the last step, since I believe you understand how to do that part.

This short description can now be translated into Java. Notice that there is only a single loop. You can implement this as either a while or do...while loop.